# Unity Remote 5 not working with Unity 2019.3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile, game-engine, unity-remote

I've always used Unity Remote 5 with Unity and it has always worked fine.
All of a sudden I started Unity and nothing worked. The app wasn't showing anything and in the editor i couldn't even click in the game panel.
I tried:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling Unity
- Uninstalling and reinstalling Unity Remote 5
- Upgrade to a newer version of Unity
- Reinstalling mobile drivers

The SDK and JDK are installed with Unity and I've no problem with them. The mobile is connected as MPT (I've tried also PTP). USB debug is active. The Unity console doesn't show any message.

This piece of code doesn't work in any way:

```
private void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("Screen touched");
    }
}
```

When I build the game everything works, but in the editor I have no ways of testing my game. Please, help.

Comment: Can you see your device in the Editor Settings as described in the image [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityRemote5.html?_ga=2.72243795.1774507611.1580978256-1278942765.1564485958)? Unity Remote seems to be buggy, sometimes a reboot of both the mobile and PC resolves the issues. Also make sure to connect the device first, then start up Unity.

Comment: The device has never showed up. I've always chose "Any Android device" and it always worked fine. I tried rebooting everything. I tried everything, but nothing works.

Comment: I resolved the problem by changing the cable. [Also this answer was helpful too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45402965/unity-remote-5-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem by creating a new project and importing all the asset. I think that the problem was in the project, that got corrupted after the Unity update.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by manually specifying my sdk folder

[image]